# Sql server [content] named column weird behaviour?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I created SQL server Table which contains information and one of the columns should contain `content` so I called it `[content]` (*don't ask me why*).

[image]

But when I executed a simple query to return all columns : I saw that one of the column is missing (`BenefitName` column) :

Notice : I also forgot a comma between 2 columns and still - it did run successfully - yet  - without the column.

[image]

I tried to add `[conent]` without a comma right after another column and it did compile :

[image]

**Question:**

- What is going on here ? I forgot a comma and it didn't fail , Also : I don't get the `benefitName` column .

nb :

Adding the comma - does return the right result :

[image]

Comment: Read up on aliases; you've aliased `BenefitName` to `content` by leaving out that comma.

Comment: @AdrianWragg yes ofcourse , the 2 `[...]`'s distracted me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *...I forgot a comma and it didn't fail..*

What happenned was that the `[content]` became an *ALIAS* of the column `[BenefitName]`.

```
[BenefitName] AS [content]
```

is the same with

```
[BenefitName] [content]
```

since `AS` keyword is optional.

Comment: oh man  stupid me. the `[...]` confused me. ( and I also use `AS`...). of course it's an alias.....well. it happens :-)